# What could be the use of (Random.NextDouble() < 1)

Tags: c#, .net, random, mocking

I've seen in several applications I'm supporting the following sentence:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
if (rnd.NextDouble() < 1)
{
    ' Do stuff
}
```

What could be the purpose of this? rnd is going to return always a value below 1. The only thing I can think of is that if you mock Random then you would be able to deactivate some sections of the code.

What do you think? Have you found things like this?

**EDIT**: The thing is that this sentences are located on different but related sections of code and always covering entire features. That's why I tend to think that is was coded on purpose. And the code seems to have a certaing degree of quality, it this was a mistake I would be suprised providen all the other code.

Comment: If I may ask, is it just out of curiosity that youre asking, or are you wanting to implament it? If so, what Ideas do you have?

Comment: or someone never read the documentation for `NextDouble()` ?

Comment: it seems like redundant code, could it be that originally they tested the app using other values than 1, and out of laziness the code remained in final release?  Unfortunately I have seen this in the past.

Comment: @NewAmbition: I have seen this on code I'm maintaining and I want to know if it's coded by error or if this some kind of hidden feature that someone is aware of.

Comment: I am not sure but this check is not required. `rnd.NextDouble` will always return in the range of 0.0 to 1.0. [Random.NextDouble Method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) > A double-precision floating point number greater than or equal to 0.0,
> and **less than 1.0**.

Comment: @wal: I don't think so. I would say that this is done on purpose.

Comment: It looks very suspicious when used without a comment, at any rate. Ask the person who wrote it. (Mocking Random to return something > 1 also seems likely to break things.)

Comment: @SoMoS, why not comment out the code, and see where (or if) the application throws an error? This will help you pinpoint what its used for.

Comment: @tc: good point. Anyway, the code has "no comment at all, anywhere", so at least it's coherent (*sigh*). I'm not sure about how mocking works, can I mock Random so only my user code uses the mocked Random or would be used by anyone (even the Framework). This way I can check if the Random class is used anymore on the applications.

Comment: If within Visual Studio simply highlight the method name and press Shift+F12 - finds all references.

Comment: If you downvote say why, otherwise don't as I cannot improve what *you think* it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but this check is not required. `rnd.NextDouble` will always return in the range 
of 0.0 to 1.0.

[Random.NextDouble Method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx)

> A double-precision floating point number greater than or equal to 0.0,
>   and **less than 1.0**.

Comment: I know this and I would say that the one that coded this also knew this. The only purpose I can think of if the mocking use but looks strange anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Random` in question is indeed [`System.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), I can't see any functional reason for having this.

All I could speculate is that perhaps the writer wanted a code block that they could easily (while debugging / developing) run conditionally (by changing the `1` to `0`) or only some of the time (by changing the `1` to some value between `0` and `1`). But really, this isn't a well-known idiom, so you'd have to ask the person who wrote it, hence my vote to close as too localized.

Comment: I honestly think that SO is focussing way too much on closing things. This is a real question that can have a real answer so I think that it shouldn't be closed. Even if the check was done by mistake if someone in the future finds the same mistake he will know it has not purpose at all so maintainning the question makes sense to me.